# rename returns NoneType object

Tags: python, pandas

I have tried several different ways to rename columns in my dataframe and none are working.
I want to change the column name "Species" to read "Common Name".

```
> general = pd.read_csv('july_4/general.csv', usecols=['Species', 'Count'])
> general
                   Species  Count
0         Downy Woodpecker      1
1         Northern Flicker      1
2         Eastern Kingbird      2
```

Using rename() does not change the columns:

```
> general.rename({'Species': 'Common Name'}, inplace=True) 
> general
                   Species  Count
0         Downy Woodpecker      1
1         Northern Flicker      1
2         Eastern Kingbird      2
```

Reassigning the variable returns a NoneType object:

```
> general = pd.read_csv('july_4/general.csv', usecols=['Species', 'Count'])
> general = general.rename({'Species': 'Common Name'}, inplace=True)

> general[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):

  Cell In[85], line 1
    general[0]

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`None` is the expected return value when you use the `inplace` option. The reason your *column* is not being renamed is because a dict as a positional argument attempts to rename *rows*.

For example (omitting `inplace=True` for simplicity):

```
>>> import pandas
>>> df = pandas.DataFrame({"A": [1,2,3], "B": [4,5,6]})
>>> df
   A  B
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6
>>> df.rename({0: 9})
   A  B
9  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6
>>> df.rename({"A": "A1"})
   A  B
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6
>>> df.rename(columns={"A": "A1"})
   A1  B
0   1  4
1   2  5
2   3  6
```

As you can see, a *row* named `"A"` would be renamed, if it existed. Use the `columns` keyword argument to rename columns.

Answer (score 1):

The parameter `inplace` causes the error. If you use `inplace=True`, then dataframe changes in place. `inplace` returns `None`, hence the error.

You can solve this problem in two ways:

1. general.rename(columns={'Species': 'Common Name'}, inplace=True)
2. general = general.rename(columns={'Species': 'Common Name'})

Comment: Worth noting that `inplace` was not the issue, but the lack of a `columns` keyword argument (or some other correct way of renaming a column).

Answer (score 0):

you are using `inplace=True`, which means the method work *in place* and it will return `None`. In any case, all you want is to specify the correct axis in `rename` to get what you want:

```
In [24]: general.rename({'Species': 'Common Name'}, axis=1)
Out[24]:
           Common Name  Count
0 Downy     Woodpecker      1
1 Northern     Flicker      1
2 Eastern     Kingbird      2
```

Comment: I wonder, just how many ways *are* there to rename a column? :)

Comment: @chepner ah, the above is the old way, I think using `columns=....` is the preferred way nowadays

Comment: I used it in my answer because it was the first one I stumbled on. There's at least one more way (using the `index` keyword argument) that I skipped because it seemed too general to worry about for this question.